# Do I need to set the wifi UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key if my app depends on calling web services?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, info-plist

The docs say:

> "Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits)
>   access to the networking features of the device."

It uses WiFi when available, but also 3G / mobile data.

I am afraid if I specify this key, it effectively means that the app doesn't work without a WiFi connection. Which would be wrong. It just requires internet access.